# Make username@machine bold in Terminal's ZSH shell but not the command's output

Tags: terminal, command-line, zsh

How can I make Terminal, using ZSH shell, display `username@machine current_folder %` in bold? I know it has to do with editing PS1 variable in zshrc file located in /etc folder. I have tried that, I added `%B`, like this `PS1="%n@%m %1~ %# "` => `PS1="%B%n@%m %1~ %# "` but that sometimes makes also output of some commands bold.

Answer (score 4):

Just terminate the bold text after the current working directory with `%b`

```
PS1="%B%n@%m %1~%b %# "
```

Comment: Thanks, but what ultimately has worked for me is: PS1="%B%n@%m %1~ %#%b ". Your solution did not make the last % character bold.